# Play Framework 2.5 using JS file in index.scala.html

Tags: javascript, html, playframework-2.0, twirl

I'm currently attempting to refactor my repeated JavaScript code from my xyz.scala.html files into a separate main.js file, which can then be linked to using something like the below (from my scala.html files):

`<script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js")'><script>`

And using the below in my conf/routes file:

```
GET     /js/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public/javascripts", file)
```

Having Googled around I'm struggling to find a simple way of using JS from a file in my Play Framework application and setting up the conf/routes file.

Does anyone know a simple way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Public assets folders**

[image: Public assets folders]

**Record in the `routes` file**

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

**Script loading in twirl template**

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```